# How can one increase the IP3 of a low noise amplifier (LNA)?

Tags: rf, analog, circuit-design

Is lowering the gain of an LNA the only method to increase IP3?

Is there any other technique to increase IP3 without sacrificing the gain?

Comment: From a system perspective there might be things that can be done but, from a device perspective no.

Comment: If it's a component ... no. If you're modifying its design .. maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (assuming you're not doing anything wrong with the amplifier so far, like supplying it with a supply voltage that's lower than appropriate).

The IP3 is a central limitation of the physics of your amplifier's active components. You'd need a different amplifier.

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't a differential amplifier help improving IP2 only? How can it increase the IP3?

Comment: not a *differential* amplifier. You need a **different** amplifier than you're using now.

Answer (score 0):

Boost the operating current, if FET.

Insert a degeneration EMITTER resistor (or inductor) if bipolar.